# PictureBox doesn't display image

Tags: c#, bitmap, picturebox

I created a PictureBox (without layout panel) on my own and initialized it however it doesn't display any pic:

```
PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
Bitmap MyImage = new Bitmap("C://Downloads//13-flower-wallpaper.jpg");
```

What's the matter?

Comment: EVERYTHING IS IN FORM1LOAD

Comment: Did you assign that image to your pb? `pictureBox1.Image = MyImage;`  Did you add the pb to your form somehow? `this.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);`

Answer (score 0):

Your path looks wrong - for the delimiter you need to either use escaped backslash (`\\`) or a single forward slash (`/`). So it can be either:

```
Bitmap MyImage = new Bitmap("C:/Downloads/13-flower-wallpaper.jpg");
```

or:

```
Bitmap MyImage = new Bitmap("C:\\Downloads\\13-flower-wallpaper.jpg");
```

whichever you prefer.